# Understanding ss Output

Tags: networking

I have run the following command using ss.

```
# ss -ua | grep radius
UNCONN     0      0         :::radius                  :::*
```

My question is, what interface/IP does `:::radius` corespond with? What Interface does `:::*` correspond with and where is its source port information for that matter? What do the asterisks mean in the output of ss? Do they mean the same as 0.0.0.0?

Comment: `::` is the IPv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0`, that is, "any address". (Actually `ss` uses `*` for IPv4 any address.) `:*` means "any port", both in IPv4 and IPv6. `:radius` means `:1812`, from `/etc/services`. The output of the command means that some process is listening on all configured address UDPv6 port 1812 accepting datagrams from anywhere any port.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought but I needed confirmation. Thanks. If you want to make your comment an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `::` is the IPv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0`, that is, "any address". (Note: `ss` uses `*` to represent IPv4 any address.)
- `:*` means "any port", both in IPv4 and IPv6.
- `:radius` means `:1812`, from `/etc/services`.

The output of the command means that some process is listening on all configured addresses UDP port 1812, accepting datagrams from anywhere any port.